# Location of automated emails

Tags: order-status

We have a magento site. Once an order has been processed using our point of sale program, we upload an xml file to our web server. Every hour a cron job is set to run to check the folder containing the xml file so that it will update the customers status in their account on our site. Once the cron job has run, it successfully updates the status but it's supposed to send an email to the customer notifying them that the order has been processed and despatched. I've tested this out and it generates the email however the email is not sent to the customer. Instead, it's sent to our own email address.

So my question is where can I find this status email in the magento backend in order to customise it and also how would I go about making this email go to the customer instead of our own address?

Appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The email templates used for orders are located in `app/locale/{lang_ISO}/template/email/sales/`. These ones that start with `order_` are used, depening on the user (guest or registered) and the order (new or update).
These template can be overwritten from `System->Transactional Emails`.

To send an order email you need to call one of these methods on the order object `sendNewOrderEmail` - for new order and `sendOrderUpdateEmail` - for order update.
If you use this method the email should get to the customer.
Maybe you set up an e-mail address in the backend under `system->sales emails` where each order e-mail should be send in addition to sending it to the customer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've found the templates for the shipment emails which is great. I checked under sales emails and yes there are email addresses in there to send a copy of the shipment email. The problem still remains though that the customer is not receiving the shipment email. You mentioned sendOrderUpdateEmail for use with order update but are you able to tell me where this might be set so I can check?